# Using Eclipse, how can i tell what version of ANT is being used?

Tags: eclipse, ant, version

Same as original question, **using Eclipse, how can i tell what version of ANT it is configured to use?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Eclipse Helios:

- Open the Preferences dialog (`Window -> Preferences`)
- Navigate to the `Ant -> Runtime` page
- Expand the `Ant Home Entries` node on the `Classpat`h tab

This shows the path used for Ant classpath, which also reveals ANT_HOME for Eclipse.

So by default in Helios you will have something like:

```
<ECLIPSE_ROOT>/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant.jar
etc
```

On this same page, you can also change ANT_HOME to use a different version of Ant you have installed on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

Create a build file and echo $ant.version

On Helios

1. create an empty build.xml
2. ctrl+space in the empty file and select the default build file template with 2 targets
3. in the target called "default" add `<echo>${ant.version}</echo>`
4. save the file
5. right click on the build.xml in the navigator
6. select run as ant build

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Helios (version 3.6.2) the version of the various plug-in modules such as ANT can be determined in the following manner.

Select the Help -> "About Eclipse SDK" menu option
Click on the "Installation Details" button
Click on the "Plug-ins" Tab
The "Plug-in Name" column is where ANT can be found the version is in the next column.

There will probably be multiple references to ANT in the "Plug-in Name" column including

Ant Build Tool Core
Ant Launching support
Ant UI
Apache Ant

I believe the "Apache Ant" is the most relevant entry and the others deal with how ant integrates with eclipse.